# Django: Append list, then paginate

Tags: python, django, pagination

On my site, I have a list of public games for users to play. I want to paginate this list so that it only shows 20 games per page. At the same time, I want to carry over game stats so that the user can know if they've played the game, and if they've liked the game (so the URLs can change). Currently it causes my site a big ol heap of pain. I am using the built-in Paginator.

My code:

```
def games(request):
    thisuser = request.user
    games_list = Game.objects.filter(private_game=False).order_by('-pubdate')
    paginator = Paginator(games_list, 20)
    next = request.path
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        games = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        games = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        games = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    args = {'games': games}
    args.update(csrf(request))

    for game in games:
        played = (game, Result.objects.filter(player=thisuser, game=game).exists())
        liked = (game, Game.objects.filter(id=game.id, gamelikes=thisuser).exists())
        args['games'].append(played, liked)

return render(request, 'games.html', args)
```

The error is "'Page' object has no attribute 'append'"

Games model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description     = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    pubdate         = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    createdby        = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='game_creator')
    lastedit         = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    private_game     = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    private          = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='private_game_players')
    item01           = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    item01photocount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item02           = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    item02photocount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item03           = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    item03photocount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item04           = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    item04photocount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    value            = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    endby_date       = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    game_closed      = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    location         = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    gamelikes        = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='game_likes')
    photocount       = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: To use the `append()` method the value of `args['games']` would have to be a `list`. What does your `Game` model look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your code by sticking the attributes directly onto the object.

```
# ...
for game in games:
    game.played = Result.objects.filter(player=thisuser, game=game).exists()
    game.liked = Game.objects.filter(id=game.id, gamelikes=thisuser).exists()

ctx = {'games': games}
ctx.update(csrf(request))

return render(request, 'games.html', ctx)
```

When you iterate over the `games` object in your template, you can access the attributes:

```
{% for game in games %}
{{ game.played }}, {{ game.liked }}
{% endfor %}
```

The only thing to be careful about is to make sure that you don't override attributes that might be on the `game` object, e.g. by prefixing the attributes to something like `extra_has_played` or `extra_has_liked`.